# Lookup DB value from anouther table and change slightly

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to create a job management system using FileMaker Pro 14 advanced and FM Starting Point 4.6.

I have only just started looking at it so am pretty much a noob with it. Basically FM Starting Point has Projects and Estimates, Each Project can have multiple Estimates. What I have done is set it so that you have to assign a Project to a Estimate before it will save. I have used the Looked-up value in the database management to fill the Estimate ID with The Project ID that has been assigned.

Project numbers start with an A and 6 digits so for example A120000. What I want to do is change the A to a Q when the Project ID is set as Estimate ID.
Can any one point me towards the right methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at calculated fields. I would probably have one field for the digits and one for the flag, then concatenate these in a calculated field for display.

Then set up a script that triggers on change in a field, which sets the flag to the other value.

More info about calculated fields: http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/create_db.8.17.html
More info about script triggers: http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/create_layout.9.61.html